# Can external stylesheets run in Dash in the Julia REPL

Tags: julia, plotly-dash

When I use the Julia REPL it ignores the external stylesheet. The whole application is in a package. I have tried inline styling and adding the file to the external stylesheet array at the beginning of the application.

Using REPL
[image]

Using Command-line
[image]

Structure of package

- src

  - assets

    - style.jl
  - app.jl
- test

App.jl

```
controls = dbc_row([
    dbc_col(
        dbc_select(
            id="countries-dropdown",
            options = dropdownOptions,
            value="Global",
            style = Dict("color" => "black"),
        ),
        width="6",
    ), 

    dbc_col(
        dcc_datepickersingle(
            id = "date-picker",
            min_date_allowed = startDate,
            max_date_allowed = endDate,
            date = endDate,
            display_format="Do MMM YY",
        ),
        style = Dict("padding-left" => "10px"),
        width="6",
    ),
],
className = "g-0 ms-auto flex-nowrap mt-3 mt-md-0",
)
```

assets/style.css

```
.DateInput_input, .DateInput_input_1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: inherit ! important;
    Height: 35px !important;
    Width: 100% !important;
    padding-left: 3px !important;
    padding-right: 3px !important;
}
```